# How to prevent a leaflet map from zooming in when a double-click event occurs in R/shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet, tmap

I am rendering a map in R/shiny in this output widget `leafletOutput("map")` in UI.
In server, I am creating the map object using `tmap` and then in `renderLeaflet()` I use `tmap_leaflet(tmap_object)` to display the map.

I would like to click on a feature on the map, capture the coordinates where I clicked so I can select the feature I clicked. I would use this information to display a table in another widget.
I have provided a reproducible example at the end of this post.
The challenge is the following:

1. When I click once on the map, only the popup appears and my table doesn't get updated.
2. When I double-click on the map, my table gets updated but the map zooms in at the same time.

Can I, at least, prevent 1 or 2 (i.e. skip the popup and register the single-click as a proper mouse-click event that will update my table; or prevent the double-click from zooming in my map).

**REPREX:**

I have uploaded the 3 input files in this [Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YeSh-8YWyms5Z5Xfq-F0ESNgyhx0_Y3o?usp=sharing).

```r
# install required packages in they are not already installed
if(!"remotes" %in% installed.packages()){
  install.packages("remotes")
}
cran_pkgs = c("magrittr", "dplyr", "shiny", "shinyjs", "bslib", "leaflet", "sf", "tmap", "viridis")
remotes::install_cran(cran_pkgs)

# load required packages
libraries <- c("magrittr", "dplyr", "shiny", "shinyjs", "bslib", "leaflet", "sf", "tmap", "viridis")
lapply(libraries, require, character.only = T)

# Load data
district <- readRDS("district.RDS")
sectors <- readRDS("sectors.RDS")
locations <- readRDS("locations.RDS")

# Create the map with shiny
#=========================
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),  # Initialize shinyjs
  titlePanel("My test map title"),
  fluidRow(
      column(4,
        shinyjs::hidden(
            card(
              id = "detailsCard",
              style = "height: 60vh;",
              full_screen = FALSE,
              card_header("Details at click point"),
              card_body(
                tableOutput("details")
                )
            )
        )
      ),
      column(8,
      card(
        id = "mapCard",
        style = "height: 100vh;",
        full_screen = TRUE,
        card_header("Map"),
        card_body(
          leafletOutput("map")
        )
      )
   )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # create the tmap object
    tmap_object <- tm_shape(district) + 
      tm_borders(col = "#A76948", alpha = .6, lwd = 3) +
      tm_shape(sectors) +
      tm_borders() +
      tm_fill(col = "number_of_clients",
              title = "number of clients",
              style = "jenks", 
              palette = cividis(6),
              id = "sector", # to specify which column to use for tooltips
              alpha = .6) + 
      tm_view(bbox = st_bbox(district))  # Set the initial extent to fit the AoI layer
    
    # convert the tmap object to a leaflet map 
    tmap_leaflet(tmap_object) 
  })
  
  # Create a reactive value to store the clicked coordinates
  clicked_coords <- reactiveValues(lon = NA, lat = NA)
  
  # Observe the map click event
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    clicked_coords$lon <- input$map_click$lng
    clicked_coords$lat <- input$map_click$lat
    
    # Show the details card when a sector is clicked
    shinyjs::toggle("detailsCard")
  })
  # filter my data and display only the records relevant for the clicked spot
  output$details <- renderTable({
    # Filter the data given the sector clicked and display as a table
    longitude <- as.numeric(clicked_coords$lon)
    latitude <- as.numeric(clicked_coords$lat)
    clicked_spot <- st_sfc(st_point(c(longitude, latitude)), crs=4326)  # Create an sf point
    clicked_spot <- st_transform(clicked_spot, crs = st_crs(district)) # Re-project the point appropriately
    clicked_sector <- sectors %>% st_filter(clicked_spot, .predicate = st_intersects) 
    my_clients <- locations %>% st_filter(clicked_sector, .predicate = st_intersects) %>% st_drop_geometry()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
#>  os       Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_United States.utf8
#>  ctype    English_United States.utf8
#>  tz       Africa/Johannesburg
#>  date     2023-12-14
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package           * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  abind               1.4-5      2016-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  base64enc           0.1-3      2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  bslib             * 0.6.1      2023-11-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  cachem              1.0.8      2023-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  class               7.3-22     2023-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  classInt            0.4-9      2023-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  cli                 3.6.1      2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  codetools           0.2-19     2023-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  colorspace          2.1-0      2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  crosstalk           1.2.0      2021-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  DBI                 1.1.3      2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  dichromat           2.0-0.1    2022-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  digest              0.6.33     2023-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  dplyr             * 1.1.4      2023-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  e1071               1.7-13     2023-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  ellipsis            0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  evaluate            0.21       2023-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  fansi               1.0.4      2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  fastmap             1.1.1      2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  fs                  1.6.3      2023-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  generics            0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  ggplot2             3.4.3      2023-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  glue                1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  gridExtra           2.3        2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  gtable              0.3.3      2023-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  htmltools           0.5.7      2023-11-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  htmlwidgets         1.6.2      2023-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  httpuv              1.6.11     2023-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  jquerylib           0.1.4      2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  jsonlite            1.8.7      2023-06-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  KernSmooth          2.23-21    2023-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  knitr               1.43       2023-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  later               1.3.1      2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  lattice             0.21-8     2023-04-05 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  leafem              0.2.0.9021 2023-08-14 [1] Github (r-spatial/leafem@09c65e6)
#>  leaflet           * 2.2.1      2023-11-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  leaflet.providers   2.0.0      2023-10-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  leafsync            0.1.0      2019-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  lifecycle           1.0.3      2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  lwgeom              0.2-13     2023-05-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  magrittr          * 2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  memoise             2.0.1      2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  mime                0.12       2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  munsell             0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  pillar              1.9.0      2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  pkgconfig           2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  png                 0.1-8      2022-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  promises            1.2.1      2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  proxy               0.4-27     2022-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  purrr               1.0.2      2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  R.cache             0.16.0     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  R.methodsS3         1.8.2      2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  R.oo                1.25.0     2022-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  R.utils             2.12.2     2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  R6                  2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  raster              3.6-23     2023-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  RColorBrewer        1.1-3      2022-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  Rcpp                1.0.11     2023-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  remotes             2.4.2.1    2023-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  reprex              2.0.2      2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  rlang               1.1.1      2023-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  rmarkdown           2.23       2023-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  rstudioapi          0.15.0     2023-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  sass                0.4.7      2023-07-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  scales              1.2.1      2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  sessioninfo         1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  sf                * 1.0-14     2023-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  shiny             * 1.8.0      2023-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  shinyjs           * 2.1.0      2021-12-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  sp                  2.0-0      2023-06-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  stars               0.6-3      2023-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  styler              1.10.2     2023-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  terra               1.7-39     2023-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  tibble              3.2.1      2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  tidyselect          1.2.0      2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  tmap              * 3.3-4      2023-09-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  tmaptools           3.1-1      2021-01-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  units               0.8-3      2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  utf8                1.2.3      2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  vctrs               0.6.4      2023-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  viridis           * 0.6.4      2023-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  viridisLite       * 0.4.2      2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  webshot             0.5.5      2023-06-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  withr               2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  xfun                0.40       2023-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  XML                 3.99-0.14  2023-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  xtable              1.8-4      2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  yaml                2.3.7      2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Even though it is good that you share your code, you increase the likelihood of an answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. Otherwise, whoever wants to answer your question has to do it by herself. Especially for shiny functions, that is an increased burden

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're after, but this works for me with just one click. I think there's better ways to do achieve this (`reactive()`s and the `NULL` checks) but it works and makes sense in my head.

I would also suggest that using `shinyjs::toggle()` is probably not what you want since it will toggle the table on each click regardless of whether it the click intersected with data or not. I.E., I could click the same place twice and it would show the table and then hide it which I'm not sure is what the user would expect. You could maybe use a show/hide button instead?

This code also adds a marker where the user clicks which I found to be useful. Anyway, hope this helps!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

# data gen ----

# outline
outline <- system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf") |>
    sf::st_read() |>
    sf::st_geometry() |>
    sf::st_union() |>
    sf::st_as_sf() |>
    sf::st_transform("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# gen some polygons
poly <- outline |>
    sf::st_sample(40) |>
    sf::st_buffer(units::as_units(10, "mi")) |>
    sf::st_as_sf() |>
    dplyr::mutate(id = seq_len(dplyr::n())) |>
    dplyr::mutate(color = viridisLite::viridis(dplyr::n())) |>
    dplyr::rowwise() |>
    dplyr::mutate(label = htmltools::HTML(
        paste0(
            "<b>ID:</b> ", id, " <br/>",
            "<b>Color:</b> ", color
        )
    )) |>
    dplyr::ungroup() |>
    sf::st_set_agr("constant")

# ui ----

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    leaflet::leafletOutput("map"),
    shiny::tableOutput("tab")
)

# server ----

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # initial map
    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
        leaflet::leaflet() |>
            leaflet::addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") |>
            leaflet::addPolygons(
                data = outline,
                fillOpacity = .15,
                fillColor = "black",
                color = "black", weight = 2
            ) |>
            leaflet::addPolygons(
                data = poly,
                fillColor = ~color,
                fillOpacity = .75,
                stroke = FALSE,
                label = ~label
            )
    })

    # click logic
    observe({
        # clear previous click
        leaflet::leafletProxy("map") |>
            leaflet::clearMarkers()

        # get new click
        click <- input$map_click

        # add click to map
        leaflet::leafletProxy("map") |>
            leaflet::addMarkers(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat)
    }) |>
        shiny::bindEvent(input$map_click)

    # pt
    pt <- shiny::reactive({
        if (!is.null(input$map_click$lat)) {
            pt <- sf::st_point(
                c(
                    input$map_click$lng,
                    input$map_click$lat
                )
            ) |>
                sf::st_sfc(crs = 4326) |>
                sf::st_as_sf()

            return(pt)
        } else {
            NULL
        }
    })

    # intersects
    intersects <- shiny::reactive({
        if (!is.null(pt())) {
            sf::st_intersection(pt(), poly) |>
                sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
                dplyr::select(-label)
        } else {
            NULL
        }
    })

    # table
    output$tab <- shiny::renderTable({
        if (is.null(intersects())) {
            return(NULL)
        }
        if (nrow(intersects()) > 0) {
            intersects()
        } else {
            NULL
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the addition of a marker where the user clicks. However, none of my initial issues is resolved. I still have to click once to bring up the popup and a second time to display the table. Isn't really a way to disable the popup altogether?

Comment: @FaustinGashakamba Ah, I think I get what you're saying. I would recommend using base leaflet to render the map instead of tmap so you can have control over those behaviors. I've edited the solution to include a label (which displays information as you hover over it instead of having to the click the point). Then, you can still click once and render the table in your app.


See [https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html) for more info on popups vs. labels in leaflet